# Is there a way to get the number of children of a git commit node?

Tags: git

I'd like to find the nth node in the commit graph from where it has 2 or more children.  So if the history was:

```
A -- B -- C -- D
      \
       E -- F*
```

And I am at `F`, I'd like to find `B` if I was searching for the 1st node with more than one child.

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: May I ask why you want to find out such a commit?

Comment: Are you trying to find the common ancestor of your branch with another?

Comment: Do you need this scripted, or visually?

Comment: Also, there's the question of deleted branches, and tags. If the E/F branch was deleted, or rebased elsewhere, do you still want B to be considered to have two children? If the second child is on a remote branch only but not a local branch (or vice versa), do you want it considered to have two children? If the second child is not on a branch at all, only on a tag, same question.

Comment: @ElpieKay, just want to see where a branch was broken off from.

Comment: @padawin, no, not looking for a common ancestor. However, that would also be useful given that only parents are pointed at and will want some tricks to reduce processing.

Comment: @joanis, no, just current graph setup is sufficient,  I didn't know that a node could have remote children.  Not sure how that would work.  If such a thing is possible, then yes, I think I would consider it having 2 children if possible.  Not sure what you mean by *"If the second child is not on a branch at all, only on a tag"*.

Comment: @Adrian then it's not a reliable method. For example, now a new branch `foo` is created from `F`, but you still find `B`.

Comment: @ElpieKay, yes, that's what I want.  *"I'd like to find the nth node in the commit graph from where it has 2 or more children."*.

Comment: @Adrian by remote children, I meant children on a locally cloned remote branch, say `origin/dev.abc` or `dev/dev.branch` if you have `dev` as a second remote. As for a child being on a tag only, imagine tagging the head of `dev.abc` and then deleting branch `dev.abc`. That will leave some commits on the tag but on no branch. Anyway, in his answer @torek gave you the hints you need to write a script to do this. And if a visual answer was enough, I would inspect the output of `git log --graph --decorate --all --format=oneline`: look for HEAD and follow it up until you see the V's in the graph.

Answer (score 1):

All of Git's internal linkages point backwards, from child to parent:

```
A <-B <-C <-D
     ↖︎            [this is an up-and-left arrow, but it may not work in some fonts]
      E <-F
```

That said, `git rev-list` has the ability to reverse the links while walking the graph.  So you can walk the graph from `F` backwards, reversing each link so as to build a list of children.  The problem here is that Git only *sees* the links it walks:

```
A-> B <-C <-D
     ↘︎            [this is a down-and-right arrow]
      E-> F
```

This means that even using the `git rev-list` option that does this (`--children`), Git will claim that `B` has *one* child, namely `E`.  To get Git to claim that `B` has two children, `E` and `C`, you must start from both `F` *and* `D` so that `git rev-list` walks back from `D` to `C` to `B`:

```
A-> B-> C-> D
     ↘︎            [this is a down-and-right arrow]
      E-> F
```

You can get Git to start at all branch names using `--branches`, or all tag names using `--tags`, or all references (including things like `refs/stash`) using `--all`.  Add `--topo-order` to the `git rev-list` command and you'll get a list of commits and their children.  From this list you will want the *last* commit that leads to `F` but also has multiple children.  Unfortunately the output from `git rev-list` here is still not terribly useful.  To do this job quickly, you might want to write your own graph reader, in which case you can do your own internal marking and can just use `git rev-list --parents --all` or similar.

(This job is much easier in Mercurial, although even there it may still be nontrivial.)

Comment: Wow!  So to do this, I have to generate the entire tree and then analyze it? *sigh* smh

Comment: So, if I was on `D`, then `rev-list` will walk `A -> B -> C -> D`?

Comment: How does git walk the linkages backwards?  Does the DB not contain actual reverse pointers or is it doing the node traversal by actually regenerating the entire tree before doing the traversal?  The latter would be really inefficient.

Comment: Git stores parent pointers only. Navigating to a parent is direct, finding children is not, so yes, it is potentially very inefficient.

Comment: So, if I was on `D`, then `rev-list` will walk `A -> B -> C -> D`, and in actuality, it's just going from where I am, traversing the parents and reporting the information backwards?

Comment: In light of this information, is there a way to just iterate over all the nodes and build the tree from that rather than iterating over all the branches and rediscovering all of the nodes where they intersect?  Or if I do iterate over all of the branches, can I get git to just report the nth child, so that I can stop when I've reached a node I've already seen?  Quite honestly, I'm not sure which would be faster as I would have to keep spawning git processes, unless I start going into the back end. :(

Comment: A branch name contains a commit hash ID. This is, by definition, the *last* commit that should be considered part of the branch. Each commit also contains some set of hash IDs, naming the parent nodes. These are the outgoing arcs in the DAG. So Git naturally works backwards: it does not go A to B to C to D, but rather D to C to B to A. See http://think-like-a-git.net/ as well (but if you're familiar with graph theory it's all pretty obvious).

Comment: Normally, both `git log` and `git rev-list` (which internally share almost all their code) do the graph walking backwards, in the arc order, and show each commit with all of its parents. There's a priority queue to handle cases where there are two or more commits to be shown. The order for multiple commit hash IDs in the priority queue is controllable but defaults to commit date (timestamp); you need to add `--topo-order` to force a topologically consistent traversal. If you're going to build your own data structure, there's no need for `--topo-order`.

Comment: Only *maintenance* commands (`git fsck` and `git gc`, primarily) actually iterate over the entire database. Everything else *must* start from nodes found via reference names (branch names, tag names, `refs/stash`, entries in the `refs/replace/` name space, and so on). You pick your starting references, visit the reachable portions of the graph, and do whatever you like with the found hash IDs. The reversal I mention above is the standard "reverse a linked list in place" trick (or "reverse the arrows" in compacting GCs): that's how `git rev-list` implements `--children`.